# Database friends list structure and query

Tags: sql

I have seen similar post but my problem is not solved i have a database table with fields user_id and friends_id

### user_id | friends_id

### 1 | 2

### 3 | 4

### 5 | 1

If I write query

```
select * 
from friends 
where user_id = 1 or friends_id = 1
```

This return

### user_id | friends_id

### 1 | 2

### 5 | 1

The problem is when I try to join friends table with profiles table,
profiles table containing display_pic now i try to write query like this

```
SELECT p.display_pic, f.* 
FROM friends f inner join profiles p on p.user_id = f.user_id
WHERE f.user_id = 1 or f.friend_id = 1
```

This query will only return display pic of user_id what I want is for first record I need display pic of 2 and for second record I need display pic of 5

I am using mysql database

Please help me Thank you.

Comment: You are query is wrong. You are searching for user_id = 3 which has only one matching row. Where as the first example you gave, you are searching for user_id =1. Make sure that you are using the id which you actually mean to. Also it helps to mention the type of database you are using. [sql server, mysql etc]

Comment: oops sorry my mistake SELECT p.display_pic, f.* FROM friends f inner join profiles p on p.user_id = f.user_id WHERE f.user_id = 1 or f.friend_id = 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT p.display_pic, f.* 
FROM friends f inner join profiles p on p.user_id = f.user_id 
WHERE f.friend_id = 1
    UNION
SELECT p.display_pic, f.* 
FROM friends f inner join profiles p on p.user_id = f.friend_id 
WHERE f.user_id = 1
```

Comment: it will show the display pic of the user itself my id is 1 but i want the display pic of my friends 2 and 5, it must get my friends info against my id...

Comment: you are right, the query is updated now. just the columns in where clause are to be swapped.

Comment: `UNION ALL` can also be used, instead of the `UNION`. One (probably costly) sorting, double-checking operation less, this way.